# HTML5 floating submit button on multiple forms with message box?

Tags: jquery, css, html, forms

I have multiple forms in my Single Page App. Each form has different number of elements and some of them will require user to scroll. Originally my Submit button was on the very bottom of the form. Some of the users asked if this button can be floating and always be visible. So I'm looking for general solution that would be applicable on all forms. One of the problems is that each form has Clear Form button on the top right corner. Second problem is that some form might have one more button next to the Clear Form. So I'm not sure what would be the best place to put Submit button? Also there is message next to the button that will notify the user if 'Record has been successfully saved.' or 'Record has been successfully updated.' . If anyone can help or propose some example what is the best solution please let me know! Thanks in advance. Here is example of one of the forms in my app:

```css
div.submitBox {
 position:fixed;
 top:40px;
 left:330px;
}
.required:before {
    content: '*';
    color: red;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
form.frmLayout {
 max-width: 1200px;
  height: 450px;
}
form.frmLayout fieldset {
 border: #ccc 2px solid;
 margin: 10px;
 border-radius:3px;
}
form.frmLayout legend {
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: #c8e2db;
 border-radius:3px;
 padding: 3px;
 border: #ccc 2px solid;
}
form.frmLayout label {
 float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
}
form.frmLayout input[type=text] { 
 text-align: left;
}
form.frmLayout input[readonly="readonly"] {
    background-color: #E0DBDD;
}
```

```html
<form name="demoForm" id="demoForm" method="POST" action="#" class="frmLayout">
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Demographic</legend>
   <div>
    <div style="float:right;">
     <span><input type="button" name="clearForm" id="clearDemo" value="Clear Form"></span>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="formItem">
    <span style="color:red;">* <b>Required Fields</b></span>
   </div>
   <div class="formItem">
    <label for="last_name" class="required">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="frm_lname" id="frm_lname" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" required />
   </div>
   <div class="formItem">
    <label for="first_name" class="required">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="frm_fname" id="frm_fname" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" required />
   </div>
   <div class="formItem">
    <label for="dob" class="required">DOB:</label>
    <input type="text" name="frm_dob" id="frm_dob" value="" size="10" maxlength="10" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" required />
   </div>
   <div class="formItem">
    <label for="gender" class="required">Gender:</label>
    <input type="text" name="frm_gender" id="frm_gender" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" title="F = Female; M = Male" pattern="[MmFf]" required />
   </div>
   <div class="submitBox">
    <span><input type="submit" name="frmSubmit" id="frmSubmit" value="Submit" /></span>
    <span style="float:right;" id="MsgDemoForm"></span>
   </div>
  </fieldset>
 </form>
```

Comment: You could check if your form is taller than the display height, and if it is, position the `submitBox` statically at the bottom of your form so it is always visible. Basically a sticky footer in this instance.

Comment: @WildBeard that sounds like a good solution. Can you please provide example? Thank you!

Comment: Sure can! Give me a moment to whip something up.

Answer (score 1):

So, you could make the submit area 'stick' to the bottom of the viewable area. This would make it so the submit button is always present, when it normally wouldn't be, but returns to its original position when it is in view.

The magic is the `stickIt()` function. It checks to see if the top of `.submitBox` is greater than the height of the `.testArea`'s viewable area. If it is absolutely position the `.submitBox` at the bottom of the viewable area.

You'll want to style everything so when it is positioned over other elements it'll look nicer instead of an unstyled button on top of your labels and inputs. From a UI/UX perspective (which I'm not an expert) I don't think this is the **best** solution but is a solution your users asked for. I say this because you want your users to scroll through all the required fields and submit them. If you present the submit button beforehand they may think the field is "complete" and attempt to submit an incomplete form.

You **could** position the submit area to the top right, in the same area the clear form button is, and disable the button until all required forms are properly filled out. This is the best of both worlds as the button is always visible but remains unusable until requirements are met.

```js
$('.testArea').on('scroll', stickIt);
stickIt();

function stickIt() {

  var submitBox = $('.submitBox'),
    testArea = $('.testArea'),
    offset = 25;

  if (submitBox.offset().top > $(this).scrollTop() + offset) {
    submitBox.addClass('sticky').css('bottom', testArea.height() + submitBox.height());
  } else {
    submitBox.removeClass('sticky');
  }

}
```

```css
.testArea {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

div.submitBox {
  width: 100%;
}

div.submitBox.sticky {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.frmLayout {
  position: relative;
}

.required:before {
  content: '*';
  color: red;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

form.frmLayout {
  max-width: 1200px;
  min-height: 300px;
}

form.frmLayout fieldset {
  border: #ccc 2px solid;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

form.frmLayout legend {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #c8e2db;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 3px;
  border: #ccc 2px solid;
}

form.frmLayout label {
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
}

form.frmLayout input[type=text] {
  text-align: left;
}

form.frmLayout input[readonly="readonly"] {
  background-color: #E0DBDD;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testArea">

  <form name="demoForm" id="demoForm" method="POST" action="#" class="frmLayout">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Demographic</legend>
      <div>
        <div style="float:right;">
          <span><input type="button" name="clearForm" id="clearDemo" value="Clear Form"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="formItem">
        <span style="color:red;">* <b>Required Fields</b></span>
      </div>
      <div class="formItem">
        <label for="last_name" class="required">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="frm_lname" id="frm_lname" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" required />
      </div>
      <div class="formItem">
        <label for="first_name" class="required">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="frm_fname" id="frm_fname" value="" size="20" maxlength="30" required />
      </div>
      <div class="formItem">
        <label for="dob" class="required">DOB:</label>
        <input type="text" name="frm_dob" id="frm_dob" value="" size="10" maxlength="10" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" required />
      </div>
      <div class="formItem">
        <label for="gender" class="required">Gender:</label>
        <input type="text" name="frm_gender" id="frm_gender" value="" size="1" maxlength="1" title="F = Female; M = Male" pattern="[MmFf]" required />
      </div>
      <div class="submitBox">
        <span><input type="submit" name="frmSubmit" id="frmSubmit" value="Submit" /></span>
        <span style="float:right;" id="MsgDemoForm"></span>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: First of all thanks for taking time to provide example. I agree with points you mentioned above and that's why I placed submit button on the bottom of the page. That will prevent user to submit incomplete form.